# Do we want to participate in Winter Bash 2016?

Tags: discussion

The [winter bash](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/Winter-Bash-2015-Hats-Off/) is a [community promotion](http://stackpromos.com/promos) and allows users to earn hats to place them on their profile pictures.

I have an email from the Stack Exchange community team, telling me that Winter Bash 2016 is ready, and will start on December 19, 2016. Because previous years have seen such a positive response, the default position is *in* - i.e. we will have hats.

If we don't want hats, we need to let the Stack Exchange team know by December 13, 2016.

> If you want in, you don't need to do anything; that's the default this year, due to overwhelming positive response in previous years. **If you want to opt out, have someone on your team reply to this e-mail to say so by Tuesday, 13 December 2016.**

If anyone has objections to hats, please post them as an answer here so the community can make its decision.

Comment: Humbly no objections: hats should be fine.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this year individuals will be able to opt-out of hats, while the site remains opted in.

Comment: I am in, i've already won my first hat

Comment: Don't forget to wear them :)

Comment: Anyone else going to miss the hats when the Winter Bash ends?

Comment: For sure. Bokky got the blue feet. I want that too. :D

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaand.. gone :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Whoever dislikes the winter bash can opt out of the hats this year:

> As always, if you're a hater of fun and hats, you don't need to participate or even see hats. You can opt out of hats by clicking the snowflake icon in the top bar, and then click the 'I hate hats' link at the bottom left. If you decide that you no longer hate hats, you can always change your mind during the season of hats.

[Read more](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/?cb=1).

Comment: [Say Farewell to Winter Bash 2016!](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/?cb=1)